# How to sort MySQL results and then get the ID of the latest 10 datetimes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, datetime

How can I take the id and timestamp results from MySQL `$row[id]` and `$row[timestamp]` and sort the results and get an array of the id's with the latest matching timestamps?
So if my MySQL database has this data in it,

`3,2015-08-24 10:38:31`, `34,2015-08-24 10:38:16`, `8,2015-08-24 10:38:51`

I will end up eventually with an array, of the ID's in order from newest to oldest timestamps.

`8,3,34`

Here is my code with information omitted.

```
$servername = "IP:PORT";
$username = "USERNAME";
$password = "PASSWORD";
$dbname = "DB";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection to the database failed. Please try again. Error: " . $conn >connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT id, timestamp FROM posts ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1,10;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$arrays = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arrays[] = $row[id];
    }
}
foreach ($arrays as $key => $id) {
    $servername = "IP:PORT";
    $username = "USERNAME";
    $password = "PASSWORD";
    $dbname = "DB";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection to the database failed. Please try again. Error: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }   
    $sql = "SELECT name,timestamp,text FROM posts WHERE id=\"" . $id . "\";";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $arrays = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s',$row[timestamp]);
            $timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
            $timedate = date_timezone_set($date, $timezone);
            $finaltimedate = $timedate->format('Y-m-d h:i:s A');
            echo "<hr><h4>" . $row[name] . "<span style=\"float:right\">Time Posted: " . $finaltimedate . "</span></h4><br>";
            echo $row[text] . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I reload the page, it just shows 2 of the same, ID=0, blog post rather than post 0 and 4 (only 2 posts).

Comment: 34 would be the oldest, not the newest, etc

Comment: it's a `select blah,blah from tablexxx order by dtColumn desc limit 10`

Comment: Can you try improving the formatting of that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I properly understand your question, then this query should work for you.

```
SELECT id, timestamp FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1,10;
```

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, but thank you for your help. This worked for me.